# Can you avoid the cubic velocity-to-drag relationship by covering the entire surface with wheels?

Tags: friction, drag, aerodynamics

If the object traveling through air is covered entirely in freely spinning small wheels (or ball bearings), then those wheels will begin to spin in accordance with the drag force felt by them. Once the wheels are spinning at the velocity of the air, then drag force goes to zero. All you'd have to consider is the energy required to get these wheels up to speed, and the rolling friction of the wheel contacting the air, and the axle friction which enables to wheels to spin.

So would covering a jet in tiny freely spinning ball bearing lower the craft's drag through the air?

Comment: What "cubic velocity-to-drag relationship"? For most aero objects, the drag increases by the velocity squared (or less).

Comment: @D.Halsey Square in terms of force, cubic in terms of power.

Comment: @John Doty That's true, but the question specifically mentions the drag.

Answer (score 2):

No. For something like airplane, drag mostly isn't caused by air "rubbing against" the object, it is due to air molecules "bouncing off" the object. The wheels don't reduce the amount of air the plane needs to push out of the way, so they won't really matter. Your idea might work for something like a submarine in an ocean of molasses, though.

Comment: Unless you're talking about hypersonic flows, air molecules don't "bounce off" objects. Please don't perpetuate this pop-sci fiction.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Unless you're talking about hypersonic flows, "molecules bouncing off the object" is not a useful way to characterize the flow.

Comment: @D.Halsey It's like a "Newton's cradle". The molecules bounce off of molecules that have bounced off of molecules that have bounced off of molecules, ... that have bounced off the surface. I do agree that "pushing the air out of the way" is a better description.

Comment: @D.Halsey I wouldn't suggest using this model for engineering applications, but if the goal is teaching physics then it seems to me that it does a good job isolating one very important aspect of how drag works. Fundamentally drag is a transfer of momentum from the object to the fluid, and "bouncing off" feels to me like the most intuitive way to say "exchanging momentum with". Considering how this momentum propagates through the air adds quite a bit of complexity in exchange for a relatively modest conceptual payoff.

Comment: If an object is sufficiently streamlined, its aerodynamic drag can be almost entirely due to skin friction (i.e. "air rubbing against the object") The bouncing of molecules is useful for understanding what pressure is, but beyond that it would be more useful to introduce the idea of continuum dynamics.

Answer (score 2):

Without wheels, you have air blowing past the plane at the speed the plane travels.

If you add wheels, air blows past the plane at speed $0$, because the outer surface of the wheels move backward to match the air. But the inside surface has to move forward at that same speed. So you now have air between the plane and the forward moving wheel surface. You haven't gained anything.

For a slow moving object, flow is relatively simple laminar flow. This means a layer of air right next to the plane moves at the speed of the plane. A layer just above that moves at a slightly slower speed. And so on until distant air hardly moves at all.

Turbulence occurs when objects move faster. This makes things much more complex. But there is still a very thin layer next to the plane that moves with the plane.

Most of the energy lost to friction goes to pushing air out of the way. Moving air has kinetic energy. Here are a couple posts on this.

[Why do bullets slow down from air friction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604112/37364)

[Simulating a fan speed given power applied to it over time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536074/37364)

Comment: "But the inside surface has to move forward at that same speed. So you now have air between the plane and the forward moving wheel surface." The inside surface between the spinning wheels/bearings and the plane would trap the air being pushed forward and not exert a netforce on the plane.

Comment: It would slow the wheels. Slower wheels would not be as effective.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to vastly underestimate the amount of wheel friction involved. Anything involving grease etc. in order to reduce bearing wear will certainly have more viscous friction than air blowing past a surface. You could of course think of aerodynamic bearings for the wheels, but then you are back at viscous friction between solid-gas. Other than everything getting more complicated, you will gain nothing.